# C# HttpWebRequest Cache

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

In my app I build a GET request intended to return a response from cache whenever the contents are the same as on the server.

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";                
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 2000;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Revalidate);
            request.Host = host;
            request.Referer = referer;
            request.UserAgent = ua;

            request.Accept = "text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                        using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            content = stream.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                }
                else content = string.Empty;
            }
```

However the `request.GetResponse().IsFromCache` always returns false even if the contents are the same (I still can successfully read it with `StreamReader`).
When I do the same two requests in browser consecutively it successfully caches.
I've tried all the possible Cache Policies. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `? I've tried all the possible Cache Policies` post that code.

Comment: `request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Revalidate);`

I've tried all cache levels though I think I need Revalidate

Comment: I don't think HttpWebRequests supports caching at all. Caching needs some kind of store to store the cache items and it has none.